# Is there way to disable next 7 dates from current date android datepicker?

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I tried so many Codes but failed Is there is any library or can we do this with an android studio built-in date picker?

This is my last tried code

```
  Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar twoDaysAgo = (Calendar) today.clone();
        twoDaysAgo.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
        Calendar twoDaysLater = (Calendar) today.clone();
        twoDaysLater.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        datePicker.setMinDate(twoDaysAgo.getTimeInMillis());
        datePicker.setMaxDate(twoDaysLater.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Are you looking to have all dates available before and after except the 7 days after current date, you want them blocked?

Comment: @MoAdel  Yes that what I looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android DatePicker doesn't support that built-in. You can either create your own custom DatePicker. Or use 3rd party library like [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options)
which allows you to also set `setMinDate`, `setMaxDate`, and `setDisabledDays` combined to achieve what you want, or even you can use `setSelectableDays` and providing calendar for prior the 7 days and another for post the 7 days.

Comment: Please if it was helpful to you, mark the answer as accepted to help others find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable past days in Date picker. Please refer below code snippets.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                       getActivity(),
                       (datePicker, year, month, day) -> {
                           
                       },
                       dateCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), dateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), dateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
               Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
               calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
               datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
               datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
               datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to disable next 7 days in Material Date Picker. To use material date picker just add gradle dependency: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'`

**In Java**

```
    private void showNext7DaysDisableDatePicker(){
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar next7Days = Calendar.getInstance();
    next7Days.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
    CalendarConstraints calendarConstraints = new CalendarConstraints.Builder()
            .setValidator(new CalendarConstraints.DateValidator() {
                @Override
                public boolean isValid(long date) {
                    return date <= today.getTimeInMillis() || date >= next7Days.getTimeInMillis();
                }

                @Override
                public int describeContents() {
                    return 0;
                }

                @Override
                public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

                }
            })
            .build();
    MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
            .setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraints)
            .build()
    .show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"MATERIAL_DATE_PICKER");
}
```

**In Kotlin**

```
    private fun showNext7DaysDisableDataPicker() {
    val today = Calendar.getInstance()
    val next7Days = Calendar.getInstance()
    next7Days.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7)

    val constraint = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
            .setValidator(object : CalendarConstraints.DateValidator {
        override fun describeContents(): Int {
            return 0
        }

        override fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel?, p1: Int) {
        }

        override fun isValid(date: Long): Boolean {
            if (date > today.timeInMillis && date < next7Days.timeInMillis) return false
            return true
        }

    }).build()
    val materialDatePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
            .setCalendarConstraints(constraint)
            .build()
    materialDatePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "MATERIAL_DATE_PICKER")

}
```